sort consult-imenu by occurrence
I am and wondering how to sort the items in consult-imenu as they occur in the buffer (by line number, say). For imenu only, they are sorted that way, but not for consult-imenu.
Specifically, I am working with AUCTeX and orderless.
Thanks for your ideas!
